# ld: error: unable to find library -lmysqlclient

Tags: freebsd

I am trying to compile my game program and it s giving me this

```
root@vps:/usr/src/Sursa/Server/source/game/src # gmake -j20
linking ../game
ld: error: unable to find library -lmysqlclient
c++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
gmake: *** [Makefile:228: ../game] Error 1
root@vps:/usr/src/Sursa/Server/source/game/src #
```

This is my Makefile path for library

```
# mysql
INCDIR += -I../../../extern/mysql
LIBDIR += -L/usr/local/lib/mysq
LIBS   += -lmysqlclient -lz -pthread -lm -lssl -lcrypto
### END
```

Comment: Which compiler version do you use ? Your compiler seems to be outdated since apparently it doesn't support c++14. Also please improve your question and remove the replicated contents by pressing the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61963187/edit) button.

Comment: gcc++49 / the one with gmake clean , gmake -j20

Comment: So here's the problem. In order to use some features of c++14 you would need GCC 5+ .Take a look at [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) . The only way to get rid of those errors is to install a newer gcc version ( or just compile it yourself).

Comment: You can issue the command "pkg search gcc" to list the packages pertaining to GCC and install a gcc5+ package via "pkg install gcc[version]".

Comment: gmake: *** [Makefile:224: .obj/abuse.o] Error 1
gmake: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from activity.cpp:1:
In file included from ./stdafx.h:38:
./event.hIn file included from :ani.cpp:1:

Comment: ./event.h:8:10: fatal error: 'boost/intrusive_ptr.hpp' file not found

Comment: I think you need to install the "boost-libs" package. If problems similar to this happened next time you run gmake , consider searching the package names and just install them.

Comment: Thank you , i think that it will work , I am not a programmer. I am developing a game server called Metin2 the official , but we can go private and and build ours , so I am triying to compile some files . game and db

Comment: If you  have programing skills , and looking for a hobby ... we  can have a chat , I am looking to work with someone who knows c++ etc

Comment: I'm glad to help and if you have any questions , my gmail address is "sepamou@gmail.com".

Comment: ld: error: undefined symbol: ERR_free_strings
>>> referenced by vio.c
>>>               vio.c.o:(vio_end) in archive ../../../extern/mysql/lib/libmysqlclie                                                                      nt.a

Comment: You are trying to use `apt-get` which is a Linux package manager and doesn't exist on FreeBSD. What are you actually doing?

Comment: I am compileing some sources for a Metin2 Server https://gyazo.com/38544d8954e64ddbe3dc1e87fe69dec5

Comment: @Alexandru Which source code are you trying to compile ? Is it [this](https://github.com/cCorax2/Source_code) ? I want to replicate your situation in linux . Also do you have any reason not to use linux instead of BSD ? Software installation is easier in linux.

Comment: @Alexandru Can you share the URI of the server source code with me to use beside [this](https://mega.nz/file/ZY1FGBzD#3tgmBRLfAfVTwC-qWo4oDAW2sq_jkGX7gADzkExn3_c) and [this](https://mega.nz/file/EZMzxD4R#w1HSgj5F14-K0nB2oLOMzvXZan-UOVKtYjNiGjc3Ioo) ? And are you trying to compile it based on [this](https://youtu.be/wogFfCnH9gA) guide ?

Comment: @ParsaMousavi Metin2 runs on FreeBsd

Comment: @Alexandru Can you give me any url address to download and test it ?

Comment: https://transferxl.com/00jzsfSPCCX5Gw

Comment: @ParsaMousavi you have to install freebsd 12.1 , an ggc++ ...and gnu gmake , to make gmake -j20 comand

Comment: @ParsaMousavi check your gmail

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your `GCC` compiler since [some features of c++14](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) is not supported by gcc4.9.

You can search the available packages in FreeBSD using

```
pkg search <package_name>
```

and install whatever you want via

```
pkg install <package_name>
```

Note : you might need sudo before those commands if your current user is not `root`

Finally if you have problems such as

```
Fatal error : "some_file"."some_extension" file not found
```

you can search the package name via the aforementioned command and install them in order to compile successfully.

For example to mitigate the following error

```
fatal error: 'boost/intrusive_ptr.hpp' file not found
```

you can install the `boost-libs` package.